# Redis (Community): non-cluster replications and fail-over

Tags: redis

I understand that a fail-over in the non-cluster replication setup works only by manual intervention.

I've set up the following non-cluster replication (that is, with total 3 nodes):

```
       node1 (master)
      /      \
   node2     node3
  (slave1)   (slave2)
```

Let's say that node1 is broken.

So, I issue "`replicaof no one`" on node2, trying to make it as the new master. (For this, Redis restart is NOT required, right?)

In this example, is it assumed that I need to make the following changes, **all manually?**

```
1. fix and reconfigure node1 to make it as a slave of node2 (new master)? - Redis restart is indeed required.

2. reconfigure node3 to make it as a slave of node2 (new master) instead of node1 (original master)? - Redis restart is also required.
```

I just want to verify to see if I understand it correctly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need to do it manually. Instead, you should use Redis Sentinel to do the failover stuff. Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for detail.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it automatically with Sentinel but this non-cluster manual fail-over setup is one of the possible configurations, I think, and some people may prefer this to the Sentinel cluster automated way.